# preg_replace removes every first number in the output

Tags: php

`preg_replace` removes every first number in the output when printing to TCPDF. What could be the problem? My code is as follows:

```
$return .= preg_replace('/(\d)+(st|nd|rd|th)([^\w\d]|$)/', '$1<sup>$2</sup>$3', $ttl2);
```

Comment: Maybe you should put the "+" operator inside the first capture group?: `(\d+) `instead of `(\d)+`

Comment: Thank you so much  Eduardo Escobar. Your method works as well. I love to add to my knowledge. Cheers...

Answer (score 0):

I got it guys. I hope this is going to help someone someday. I needed to add a space between the & variable and the $1. Look here (*$) /', '$1*). The correct code is as below:

$return .= preg_replace('/(\d)+(st|nd|rd|th)([^\w\d]|$) /', '$1<sup>$2</sup>$3', $ttl2);